# How do I simplify the following code which solves the attached challenge?

Tags: java

I recently downloaded an app called "SoloLearn" to improve my coding skills as I am a beginner with Java while I am not at home. Today I solved the following challenge: [image: challenge]
Everything worked but I have a feeling that there is a much easier way to get it done.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Program {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      String input = s.nextLine();
      s.close();
      System.out.println(replace(input));
  }

  public static String replace(String input)
  {
    ArrayList <Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
      String number = input.substring(i, i + 1);

      String lastChar;
      if(i != 0)
      lastChar = input.substring(i - 1, i);
      else
      lastChar = "";

      if(isNumber(number) && Integer.parseInt(number) >= 0 &&  Integer.parseInt(number)<= 10)
      {
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(number));
      }
      if(lastChar.equals("1") && number.equals("0"))
      {
        numbers.add(10);
      } 
    }
    String replacer = "";

    if(numbers.size() > 0)
    {
    for(int number : numbers)
    {
      switch(number)
      {
      case 0: replacer = "zero";
      break;
        case 1: replacer = "one";
        break;
        case 2: replacer = "two";
        break;
        case 3: replacer = "three";
        break;
        case 4: replacer = "four";
        break;
        case 5: replacer = "five";
        break;
        case 6: replacer = "six";
        break;
        case 7: replacer = "seven";
        break;
        case 8: replacer = "eight";
        break;
        case 9: replacer = "nine";
        break;
        case 10: replacer = "ten";
        break;
      }
      input = input.replace(number + "", replacer);
    }
    } else
    {

      return input;
    }
    input = input.replace("onezero","ten");
    return input;
  }

  public static boolean isNumber(String word)
  {
    try
    {
      Integer.parseInt(word);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles. Also, please copy and paste the text of the task description instead of embedding an image.

Comment: I hate it when such challenges are themselves written by utter nitwits. I mean you've got a lot of **number characters** but you decide that for **numbers 10 or under** you replace with the word. What the f* is a "number character"? Has the writer ever considered calling it a **digit**? "He who cannot teaches" in optima forma.

Comment: Bug: in the string `"1 1111"` all digits are replaced.

Comment: To make this question complete, please add your unit tests so that we can see which edge cases you forgot to handle.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Additionally, there's no indication that you're permitted to re-publish it here. Please [edit] your post to incorporate your own description of the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

### better splitting method

instead of comparing each character of the string, use an regex!

```
String input = ...
String output = new String(input);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    String occurrence = m.group();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    if (number >= 0 && number <=10){
        String numberWord = replace(number);
        output = output.substring(0,m.start())+
            output.substring(m.start()).replace(occurrence, numberWord);
    }
}
```

### avoid magic numbers

instead of returning the replacement for numbers in code you should define them separately - this allows you to change language easier and offers more maintaince on further usage. (here magic numbers are these `Strings` of wach number)

```
private final String[] mapping = {"zero", "one", ..., "ten"};

public String replace(int number){
    return mapping[number];
}
```

### naming

`replace` is a generic name and should have a better name. `toWord` might be more suitable but it's up to you.

### fun fact

[image]
(Copyright: [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/208/))

### improvement

thanks to [RoToRa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2035/rotora) i learned how to properly use `StringBuffer` and `Matcher`

```
String input = ...
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    if (number >= 0 && number <=10){
       m.appendReplacement(sb, mapping[number]);
    }
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String output = sb.toString();
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. `String.replace` will always replace the first occurrence even if it was skipped in previous iterations of the loop. For example, `"12 and 1"` becomes `"one2 and one"`.

Comment: @RoTaRa sorry, you are right, it replaces the first occurences - i've enriched my test string into the following: `String input = "i need 12 apples and 4 pumpkins - at 10 o'clock. There is 0 chance of failing.  and 1 for the test";` i have adjusted the code - thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: BTW, have a look at `Matcher`s methods `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` which were designed to handle multiple replacements like this.

Comment: @RoTaRa - i was reading the [Matcher API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) but i'm still not very good in using regexs - thanks you for sharing your knowledge! (i'll adjust my answer, when i know how to apply your hints)... **as Graditude i'll add a pic from XKCD** that came up to my mind, when working with regex...

Comment: There are many cases where regular expressions are either over-kill or create difficult to understand code, however in this case I believe it is a good solution.

Comment: XKCD : fixed now! - thank you very much =)

Comment: @MartinFrank I've added an enhanced solution as answer. I hope your solution stays the accepted one as it more closely matches the challenge level.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using a `StringBuilder` rather than manipulating the input string, would be more appropriate here.  Using a string array of the number words can reduce the whole thing to basically a simple loop.  Something like this would work:

```
static String[] words = {
    "zero",
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
    "seven",
    "eight",
    "nine",
    "ten"
};
static String replaceNums(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int limit = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        char temp = input.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(temp)) {
            if (i < limit - 1 && temp == '1' && input.charAt(i + 1) == '0') {
                sb.append(words[10]);
                ++i;
            } else {
                sb.append(words[temp - '0']);
            }
        } else {
            sb.append(temp);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This solution replaces all numbers greater than 10, for example `"11"` becomes `"oneone"`, but should stay `"11"`.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to take a look at the String Builder Class.

Answer (score 1):

The deeper you go the more exceptions you'll find when it comes to the number representation. It is for a reason that the text is just lowercase, but it doesn't specify if you can find e.g. floating points.

Here is a more advanced example which tries to be a bit more practical for real world situations and minimizes the code. Note also the use of constants (`static final` class fields in Java).

Also note the explanation of the regular expression in the comments. For hard-to-read regular expressions I would very much add this in my own code as well, and explain **what** it tries to do at the very least. Otherwise the next programmers will have a hell of a time figuring it out themselves.

Code without integer literals should generally be preferred over code with integer literals most of the time. Let the computer do the counting.

```
private static final String[] NUMBER_NAMES = new String[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
        "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };

// A digit which is not preceded or followed by another word character,
// using negative lookbehind & lookahead).
// Word characters (`\\w`) include digits.
// Comma's and dots are also excluded. 10 is a special case.
private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<!(\\w|[.,]))(\\d|10)(?!(\\w|[.,]))");

public static String replaceNumbersWithNumberNames(String test) {
    StringBuilder lineWithNumberNames = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher numberMatcher = NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(test);
    while (numberMatcher.find()) {
        String numberName = NUMBER_NAMES[Integer.parseInt(numberMatcher.group())];
        numberMatcher.appendReplacement(lineWithNumberNames, numberName);
    }
    numberMatcher.appendTail(lineWithNumberNames);
    return lineWithNumberNames.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // digit at start, end, within a word, a 10 and 100, handled correctly!
    String test = "4 (nor 10 or 100 nor 0.5, even if you're XS4ALL) shalt thou not count,"
            + " neither shalt thou count 2, excepting that thou then proceedeth to 3";
    System.out.println(replaceNumbersWithNumberNames(test));
}
```

This will print:

```
four (nor ten or 100 nor 0.5, even if you're XS4ALL) shalt thou not count, \
neither shalt thou count two, excepting that thou then proceedeth to three
```

Apologies for the Pythons for the addition between parentheses.

Comment: i did the same right now =) and added that to my answer - RoToRa pointed out the same point as you do... (proper usage of Regex and Stringbuffer)

Comment: your regex is better! far better +1